# How to evenly space three horizontally aligned buttons with bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

If I enclose with a `<div>` with `class="row"` and give each button `class="span4"` the buttons fill the total width of the screen.

I want each button to be only as wide as the text which it contains, with the centers being at `25%`, `50%` and `75%` of the `width`.

```
             [aaa]                        [bbb]                     [ccc]
```

**not**

```
[            aaa             ][            bbbb         ][            cccc            ]
```

I am new to bootstrap and not a CSS guru.

How do I achieve this?

My buttons also have `class="btn-outline btn-default"`, but that shouldn't affect things (I think) .

By the way, I am currently considering exactly 3 buttons, but if a generic solution for any number is just as easy, that would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first of all from your classes it seems you are still using [bootstrap-v2](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-v2), try using [bootstrap-v3](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-v3) (v4 it is still in <strike>alpha</strike> beta[now] stage), and you can achieve what you want with this:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px dashed red /* demo */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE ([bootstrap-v4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-v4))

For those who are using/want to use bootstrap V4, here is how:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px dashed red /* demo */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `div` with `class="row"` and 3 `div` with the `class="span4 text-center"` and put a `button` in each of these

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap way would be

```css
.col-md-3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="btn-outline btn-default">text</button></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="btn-outline btn-default">text</button></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="btn-outline btn-default">text</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

or to do it using plain CSS and flexbox

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col-md-4 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn-outline btn-default">text</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn-outline btn-default">text</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn-outline btn-default">text</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```